# How to access website via IPv6 with Groovy or Java

Tags: java, sockets, http, groovy, ipv6

I'm trying to access a webpage via IPv6 but always get a "NoRouteToHostException: No route to host". I tried the following:

```
println 'http://[2001:4810:0:0:0:0:0:110]:80/'.toURL().text
```

results in:

```
Caught: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at IPv6Tester.run(IPv6Tester.groovy:116)
```

then I tried:

```
def authSite = new groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder( 'http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80/' )
println authSite.get( path: '/search/users' ) { resp, headers ->
    println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
}
```

which resulted in:

```
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80: No route to host
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80: No route to host
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.NoRouteToHostException) caught when connecting to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80: No route to host
Apr 04, 2015 9:07:14 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect to {}->http://[2620:109:c00d:100:0:0:c765:a381]:80
Caught: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:304)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:71)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:220)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:164)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:515)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder.get(HTTPBuilder.java:285)
    at groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder$get.call(Unknown Source)
    at IPv6Tester.run(IPv6Tester.groovy:120)
```

The same happens with Jsoup:

```
def profilePage = Jsoup.connect('http://[2001:4810:0:0:0:0:0:110]:80/').userAgent(USER_AGENT).timeout(TIMEOUT).get()

Caught: java.net.ConnectException: No route to host
java.net.ConnectException: No route to host
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:439)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:424)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:178)
    at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:167)
    at org.jsoup.Connection$get$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at IPv6Tester.run(IPv6Tester.groovy:126)
```

Btw. if I open a Socket from my IPv6 to the remote IPv6 I can read the root page (but not a specific path on the server).

I assume that I have to use a Socket with a bound local IPv6 address to access the remote IPv6 Adress but I couldn't find a way to do so. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How did you set up "your" IPv6 address? What are the IPv6 routes?

Comment: With the Socket I used socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(localIPAddress, 0)); where localIPAddress is the first Inet6Adress found in the NetworkInterface Addresses of "en0". I did not set this Inet6Adress / Socket as I do not know how/where to set this.

Comment: You can't solve this problem from code alone; this is an OS level problem and more accurately a network routing problem. And for this you need to delve into your OS configuration, starting with the network routes.

Comment: I hoped there is a way to somehow "inject" the IPv6-Socket into one of the the HTTP-Libraries. Do you have a link for the configuration of network routes on Linux?

Comment: Not one particular link, no; but you want to debug the output of `ip route show` for instance. But this question really has its place on serverfault, not here.

Comment: just so it is said: above code works fine against e.g. the ipv6 address of google.  the problem is your network.

Answer (score -1):

The error you received, "No route to host", is correct.

Neither of the IP addresses you are trying to reach is routable or reachable from the global Internet.

To resolve the problem, connect to a valid, live IPv6 address.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. I connected to the IPv6 address with a socket and could read from it (i.e., get the "homepage" / root page). I used the IPv6 Address of "ipv6.whatismyv6.com" and "linkedin.com". Both worked and therefore I assume the server were live and could be connected from my computer. 
Or do you mean that the IPv6 Adress has to be stated in another ("valid") format - if so which would be the valid format?

Comment: Maybe they are only reachable from your location? I cannot reach them from the U.S.